# Why isn't working WooCommerce session inside shortcode?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, session

Hope you're doing great! I am trying to print the WC()->session->get inside a shortcode but getting error , bellow is my code and error

```
function set_session(){

    global $woocommerce;
    WC()->session->set( 'some_data_get' ,' some_data_get' );    

}
add_action( 'init', 'set_session' );

function show_session(){

   global $woocommerce;
   var_dump(  WC()->session->get( 'some_data_get' ) );

}
add_shortcode( 'show_session', 'show_session' );

do_shortcode('[show_session]');
```

here is error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in E:\OFFICE-SERVER\htdocs\aspw\wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\functions.php:335
```

Comment: Well, if you call `do_shortcode('[show_session]');` just like that (i.e. not from a proper hook), then that would cause the error. Have you actually tried adding `[show_session]` manually to the post content?

Comment: thanks ! you right